# InfoPath 2013 form works in Preview and fails when uploaded to server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

We are migrating an application from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2013. 
As part of this, I am migrating Code based InfoPath Form 2007 to InfoPath 2013. I updated all the data connections, web service connections and when I clicked on Preview, everything works fine.

When I published this InfoPath to Server I am receiving - **'Cannot connect to remote server error'**. 
Web services are on remote server. I cannot connect to the Web Service on server.

I see these in ULS logs

1. Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri 'WEBSERVICE URL'

2. Internal web service routing is NOT enabled.

As the form works fine on Preview, can i assume that the infopath form code is all good and there must be some with connections?

Comment: I am not the developer of this application, so it took a while to understand the code. After debugging the code, i identified that the issue is something related to our code. The code requires the site to work with "http"://Servername:port/" and the AAM was not setup for this. After setting up Alternate access mapping the issue is resolved. It worked in my preview as this requirement to work with "http"://Servername:port/" is only when the form is opened in browser. The code said if(browser){ code related to AAM }. This method was skipped in preview.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured InfoPath Forms Services Web Service Proxy In SharePoint 2013 Central Administration?

Try to enable InfoPath forms service web proxy like this blog:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-infopath-forms-services-web-service-proxy-in-sharepoint-2013-central-a/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes We did configure InfoPath Form Services WebService Proxy.